# Findroot with 6sin

Tags: equation-solving

My question is how to use findroot to this equation 6sin(3x)+2x-2=0.
I have tried everything I can, but Mathematica only wright the equation different like -2 + 2 x + 6 sin[3 x]].

Comment: Have you tried the proper *Mathematica* symbol for sine, namely `Sin[3 x]`?

Comment: No, do u mean sin[z] ?

Comment: Ref: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeMathematicalFunctions.html

Comment: Why would I write `z` when you write `x`?

Comment: I looked up proper Mathematica symbol for sine and thats what came up

Comment: It should have told you `Sin[z]`, then, not `sin[z]`.  (Note the capital "S".)

Comment: I think im writing it completely wrong, Findroot[6 Sin[3 x] + 2 x - 2]

Comment: "I have tried everything I can" <- What exactly have you tried?  Show the code you entered, show the output you got, and tell us what output you want instead.  Please [read this guide](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2131/12), click the edit button below your post, and improve it. Do this before adding further comments, otherwise the question will likely get closed.

Comment: Attention to capitals also applies to `FindRoot`.  Attention to following the argument pattern to `FindRoot` given in the documentation is also important.  Something like `FindRoot[6 Sin[3 x] + 2 x - 2, {x, 1.2}]` -- You can look up what the `1.2` is about in the docs. I made it up at random.

Answer (score 3):

[`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) will provide all solutions

```
soln = NSolve[6 Sin[3 x] + 2 x - 2 == 0, x, Reals]

(*  {{x -> -1.7168}, {x -> -1.34659}, {x -> 0.101401}, {x -> 1.0531}, {x -> 
   1.98311}, {x -> 3.46256}, {x -> 3.7905}}  *)
```

Verifying,

```
6 Sin[3 x] + 2 x - 2 /. soln // Chop[#, 10^-14] &

(*  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}  *)

Plot[{6 Sin[3 x], 2 - 2 x}, {x, -2, 4},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5],
   Point[{x, 2 - 2 x} /. soln]}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use the [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) to get initial estimates for [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html)

```
soln2 = FindRoot[6 Sin[3 x] + 2 x - 2, {x, #}] & /@
  {-2, -1.5, 0, 1, 2, 3.5,
    4}

(*  {{x -> -1.7168}, {x -> -1.34659}, {x -> 0.101401}, {x -> 1.0531}, {x -> 
   1.98311}, {x -> 3.46256}, {x -> 3.7905}}  *)
```